# Problems with an orphaned replication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication, database-replication, transactional-replication

I'm pretty new to SQL Server, so of course I'm doing all the DBA tasks. I pulled a boneheaded move last week, and when I did a restore on a test DB, it overwrote the replication. So, I deleted as best as I can see the replication, which is a push replication and recreated the publication and the subscriber. I still get an error however stating The subscription to publication 'xxx_DEV' has expired or does not exist. I assume that there are some orphaned records. So how do I clean them. And are they on the source or destination server? I've already tried sp_droppublication.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [sp_removedbreplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188734.aspx) on the published db or the subscriber db. this should remove all traces of replication from the db.